# iPhone app: avoiding white screen after splash screen. Let splash screen linger, hide it after UIWebview loads? Splash screen not hiding properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, splash-screen

Our goal is simple for an iPhone app: show a splash page then hide it when a UIWebview is ready to show its page.

We need the default splash screen to linger until the UIWebview is ready to display. Otherwise, a white screen appears briefly.

Unfortunately, the splash screen fails to hide after we make it linger. The default splash screen remains visible, concealing the UIWebview underneath.

We understand this may violate Apple guidelines.

This is more for a prototype than anything, and we would like to understand what we're doing wrong. Any clues?

We're using Xcode 4.2.

### **AppDelegate.m:**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//
//  Created by Macintosh User on 6/4/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;
@synthesize imgv;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [imgv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    [imgv setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [self.window addSubview:imgv];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

### **ViewController.m:**

```
//
//  ViewController.m
// 
//
//  Created by Macintosh User on 6/4/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.cnn.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIImageView *imageView = appDelegate.imgv;
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [imageView setHidden:YES];
    imageView = nil;

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"Done loading UIWebView");
}

@end
```

**Curret ViewController.m generating errors:**

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Stroll
//
//  Created by Macintosh User on 6/4/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize splash;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];

    webView.delegate = self;

    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.cnn.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    for (id subview in webView.subviews)
        if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
            ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;

    /*
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIImageView *imageView = appDelegate.imgv;
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [imageView setHidden:YES];
    imageView = nil; */

    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webView];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"Done loading UIWebView");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

        splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:splash];
    });
}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        [splash removeFromSuperView];
    });
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to achieve it, get rid of all the code in your AppDelegate first of all. In your root view controller add an instance variable of class UIImageView called "splash".

Now in the rootViewController.m:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

        splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

        splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:splash];
    });
    }
```

Now in your webView load completion callback method/block

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

          [splash removeFromSuperView];
        });
```

so the dispatch_once makes sure the method will run once and only once in the life time of the application.

EDIT:

To get your callback:

in viewController.h -> viewC : UIViewController < UIWebViewDelegate >

in viewController.m

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{

    CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 460.0);
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];

    webView.delegate = self;

    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.cnn.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

then

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

          [splash removeFromSuperView];
        });
}
```

Comment: We're new to Objective-C: we don't have a rootViewController.m ... do you just mean the ViewController.m? Thanks! Also, which is the load completion callback method for the UIWebview?

Comment: well by root view controller I mean the first view that gets loaded when your app launches, check out UIWebViewDelegate - (it has a method called webViewDidFinishLoad:).

Comment: So if we only have a ViewController.m, then your first block of code goes there?

Comment: see the edit, and for future reference you should read and learn more about view controllers, delegates and call backs before attempting to make a splash screen. Splash screen should be the last thing you should worry about :)

Comment: Agreed. Thanks @Kaan. We'll try this, and let you know if it works!

Comment: Hi @Kaan, the default screen loads, but when including the code to remove the splash screen, Xcode displays this error: "Receiver type UIImageView for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'removeFromSuperView'". This error occurs at this line: "[splash removeFromSuperView];"

Comment: We updated the question with the current ViewController.m that causes this error.

Comment: Instances of UIImageView and any other type of subclass of UIView should respond to the method removeFromSuperView

Comment: Agreed, but it isn't working. We included the code above. Any clues, @Kaan?

Comment: we included the code as you advised (as you can see above), but it doesn't permit removeFromSuperView for some reason. Even if we put the call in another function (e.g., right after showing the splash screen), the error still appears.

Comment: we fixed it. Strange, but it generated the error if we copied & pasted but not if we typed in the line of code.

Comment: Wow, it's because removeFromSuperView should be removeFromSuperview. :)

Answer (score 0):

Default.png use as splashscreen by default, then removes automatically. But you create another  instance and place it to the view by yourself. Remove this part of code

```
imgv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imgv setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
[imgv setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.window addSubview:imgv];
```

from your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

Comment: Sorry, we need to clarify. We want the splash screen to linger to avoid the white screen that appears between the splash screen going away (by default) and the rendering of the UIWebview. So we need this code to stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

[First ViewController.m]

The reason that the splash screen is not disappearing is because the ViewDidLoad in ViewController is called before the splash screen being added to the screen window.

To be specific, the ViewDidLoad method was called around [self.window makeKeyAndVisible], right before the splash being called.

[Second ViewController.m]

You won't probably want to add splash screen here because of two reasons: 1) at ViewWillAppear, it is likely that the view hasn't been created yet; and 2) ViewWillAppear: can be called several times which you might not really want.

[The workable way]

A workable approach (what I am using) is a combination of your first and second trials. I mean

1. Add splash screen on to the window in the AppDelegate;
2. Do some background tasks to fetch data (for example, or load a webview);
3. when the task is done, post a notification. The splash screen which registered to the TaskDoneNotification will process necessary cleanup and remove itself from its superview.

Done

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do you register and capture the notification? We're doing the app mainly as a web app and therefore have limited exposure to Objective-C (and are avoiding PhoneGap because we only need to show a web page essentially in the app).

Comment: @Crashalot, you can refer to the NSNotificationCenter Class reference https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: just a reminder that do remember to remove as a observer when you dealloc the splash view