# IOS Splash screen/popup display from closed library

Tags: ios, user-interface

We own proprietary library built for IOS, used by our customers in their application. Basically the library has no UI related functionality, but When they call our library init api, we want to add a splash screen or a popup(containing our company logo) to be displayed on top of their UI.
This splash screen might be called anytime, during or after the application launch time.
Also it is possible that proprietary library init API may not be called from main thread.

Would like to know if there is a reliable/feasible solution with some direction/examples?

Thanks,

Hari

Comment: While click the button u create `UIImageView`, set top of all view and give some `TimeDelay` using `PerformSelector` and then `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this fool proof way, say if customers does not call from the main ui thread, is this still going to work? Are there any other loop holes?

Comment: I don't understand what u said, let me ask u. U have iOS app when the user try to access library u need to show `Splashscreen` right

Comment: Ours is a closed IOS library. Customers use our library in their IOS app. Now whenever customer want to use our library they start by calling init API of our closed library. We want popup or splash screen to be displayed during this time alone. We are not the master, ie we are not writing the ios app. IOS app is developed by our customer by using our proprietary library.

Comment: Check below answer it will help you.

Comment: @RameshKumar I wonder if this would work, if the calls were to be made not from the UI thread but some unrelated thread.

Answer (score 2):

Create `UIImageView` and add image and then

```
[self.window addSubview:uiimageview];

[self performSelector:@selector(dismissPopover) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

and then remove the image

```
-(void)dismissPopover
{
     [popover removeFromSuperview];
}
```

check this [iPhone app: avoiding white screen after splash screen. Let splash screen linger, hide it after UIWebview loads? Splash screen not hiding properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023198/iphone-app-avoiding-white-screen-after-splash-screen-let-splash-screen-linger?rq=1)