# Hide splash screen in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a pretty simple app that has one view that has a UIWebView. The header looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Things are working fairly well however, as I would expect, there is of course a delay between when the app launch image disappears and when the WebView content is loaded. To make this look a bit better I decided to hide the WebView when the view initially loads and only show it once the WebView itself loads, so in my controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.hidden = YES;


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    self.webView.hidden = NO;
}
```

This will just show the views background until the WebView loads, however that can still take 1-3 seconds.

A solution I am thinking about now is to keep showing the app launcher image until the WebView loads. Naturally I would need to handle error cases and such, but I'm thinking this may make for a better experience than just seeing the background color for a couple of seconds. Googling around I'm not seeing if this is possible, however I feel like it should be.

Could anyone give me some insight into this? Is it possible to configure the launch image to stay until you programmatically hide it? Is this even a solid approach? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: You would need to explicitly show the appropriate launch image yourself.

Comment: BTW - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023198/iphone-app-avoiding-white-screen-after-splash-screen-let-splash-screen-linger since it is nearly the same thing you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure the launch image to stay until you programmatically hide it?

I don't know but what you can do it's add the splashscreen (as a `UIView`/`UIImageView`) to your viewcontroller in front of the webview and hide this one when the web content is loaded.

The transition between the default splashscreen and yours shouldn't be visible.